# Java Eclipse Software Update Problem

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have Java Eclipse installed on Windows 7.

When I tried to make any software update, i receive an error.

I don't have any plugins installed.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G039k.jpg

So what is the problem.

Comment: The best way is that remove the application and reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install other build like Hellios, install JVM, JRE it might be some problem with the gateway (just thinking)... try it latter sometimes it web server problem. Last but not least restart microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a network that uses a proxy/firewall for internet access, you have to configure Eclipse with credentials to get through the proxy. Unfortuantely, I don't remember how to do that in Eclipse Ganymede (it's quite old), but searching the Preferences or Eclipse Help Contents should help.
Otherwise, it might just have been a transient problem with the update server; try again. I just hit that URL and it seems to be working.